# How to query with email id using Hibernate using Session.get()?

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I am just getting started with Hibernate. And I'm building a sample application where I'm signing up users by their email address.

And when they log in, they use that email address and password. Now, how do I get/retrieve a record/result while querying with their email ids?

My code looks like this:

```
    Configuration config = new Configuration();
    SessionFactory sessionFactory = config.configure().buildSessionFactory();
    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();

    try{
        Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
        LoginBean L = (LoginBean)session.get(LoginBean.class,loginBean.getEmail());

    }catch(HibernateException HE){
        System.out.println(HE.getMessage());
    }
```

Of course the `email` field is a `String`. And `Session.get()` takes `class,integer` as its arguments. I do have a primary key of type `Integer` but I'd like to do a search/get using the `email` field.

How do I go about it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Session.get()` finds an entity by its primary key. To find entities via other means, you need to execute queries:

```
LoginBean user = (LoginBean)
    session.createQuery("select lb from LoginBean lb where lb.email = :email")
           .setString("email", email)
           .uniqueResult();
```

Queries and JPQL are explained in the reference documentation. Read it.

Comment: Is there a way to find by other attributes without using queries ?

Answer (score 1):

U use primary key of the table to do a session.get(), if the primary key of the table is not email id then you have to write a query/criteria/sql query to match the email password.